Regarding the issue of Unreal loading multiple maps
Does Unreal support multi-threaded asynchronous loading of multiple level maps? All the maps I searched for are loaded asynchronously, without multi-threading. If there are multiple maps in my scene and each map takes about 5 seconds to load (if there are ten such maps, it will take 50 seconds to load them), asynchronous loading does not affect my operations in the scene, but as the number of levels increases, the time for all levels to load will become longer. So, may I ask if Unreal supports multi-threaded asynchronous loading of maps
When I tried to search for issues related to multi-threaded asynchronous loading of maps on the internet, the browser only popped up with asynchronous loading (whether using blueprints or C++), and there seemed to be no nodes related to multi-threading in the blueprints

https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/BuildingWorlds/LevelStreaming/HowTo/StreamWithBlueprints/

You will find many more Unreal-knowledgeable people in the Unreal Engine forums.
